# How to control the appearence of texture on certain number of faces, in Blender?

Tags: texturing, image

I am new to blender but know it's bases.

I am trying to make this ->
[image]

scene in Blender in 3D.

i don't know how to make cliff, here i am just using a plan with sculpting and texture to make the cliff. the problem is that, when the texture is applied, it's appearing at all single faces of the plan i am experimenting with some vectors but it didn't change anything. PLEASE HELP!

[image]
[image]

Image Texture ->
[image]

Also, if you have any tips on how can i improve the cliff or other scene, please tell me that too.

For Blend File - > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IXiBC1klRo_UImtVFZXEPdWi7t1q0Vrk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you probably need to unwrap again because your faces must overlap, mark some seams or use another method

Comment: where do i mark seams in a plane?

Comment: oh ok sorry I thought it was a volume, so just unwrap again?

Comment: i did that but now it's even worse, every face is now randomly taking 1/4 of the texture

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's not getting uploaded to blend-exchange. here is the drive line -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IXiBC1klRo_UImtVFZXEPdWi7t1q0Vrk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Think of every object in blender as having a hidden material slot. When you first go to assign a material to an object, it gives you Material.001 which already populates all these hidden slots. Thus, when you change Material.001 to something else, it applies to all objects and they all change. The solution is to press the plus (+) button next to the material box to assign a new slot, then the (+) plus button below the box to add a new material. This will add it to the object you selected only, and not all of them.

Comment: To fix your current issue, change whatever material is in slot 0 (your texture) back to white (so all objects turns back as well),  and then create a new material slot that is populated with your texture. Select (all) your cliff object in edit mode, select the texture from the new slot and press "Assign".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your object is actually made of seperate meshes as we can see if you do a simple unwrap:

[image]

So in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*, then unwrap again. Also it is very high poly, are you sure you need so many faces? In that case press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to untriangulate, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, choose the ratio in the *Operator* box, then unwrap again.

Comment: thank you, it worked, well i subdivided many times because i was going to sculpt it with rock brush.

Comment: yes but once you've sculpted you'd better bake the normals so that you can work with a low-poly version

Comment: Got It, Thankyou.